# How to stop Python read_csv Dataframe from converting Dates

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date, dataframe

So I have a few hundred files that I need to run a python script on. All the files are Excel CSV's. Everything is running just as it should except for dates. When I convert the csv's to a dataframe using pd.read_csv, the original dates are converted to some other format.

When I read the CSV's I am distinguishing date values by slashes, e.g. only values with '/' will be dates. However, since my data is being converted, my slashes are converted to dashes ('-') or the date format is changed to something else.

Here is some sample data:

```
csv_df = pd.read_csv(csv,keep_default_na=False, index_col=False, parse_dates=False, dtype=basestring)

Original         Pandas Conversion      Original 2   Pandas Conversion 2
1/1/1900 0:00    1900/01/01 00:00:00    6/2/2017     2017-06-02
1/1/1900 0:00    1900/01/01 00:00:00    6/2/2017     2017-06-02
1/1/1900 0:00    1900/01/01 00:00:00    12/13/2016   2016-12-13
1/1/1900 0:00    1900/01/01 00:00:00    12/13/2016   2016-12-13
1/1/1900 0:00    1900/01/01 00:00:00    5/24/2017    2017-05-24
1/1/1900 0:00    1900/01/01 00:00:00    5/24/2017    2017-05-24
```

I tried changing the dtype to object, but no fix. The parse_dates parameter is false so that shouldnt be it either. I believe it is Excel that's automatically changing the dates, but Im not sure what to do. I also cant exactly specify the columns because all the CSV's have different data in them. Any advice or help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Couldn't really figure out the actual solution.

However, what I did was to add one more row with some random text in the date column and then read the file. It then read the format correctly.

Later on, I deleted that row and all the subsequent empty rows and read it again. It worked fine then. Guess it had something to do with the file's encoding.